# Easy VSExpress Question (IsPressed vs _Click) Converting units

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I have this and it works but I am getting the same formula (_Click) one it looks like at the start. I want it to reuse the same boxes and button each time but with different formulas with each radio button. Thanks in advance for any help. V/r

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace UnitConverterFinal
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxa.Text == "")
            boxa.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(boxb.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32);
        else
            boxb.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(boxa.Text) - 32)  *  5/9);
    }

    private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "Farenheight to Celsius";
        boxb.Text = "";
        boxa.Text = "";

        if(button1.IsPressed)
        {
            if (boxa.Text == "")
                boxa.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(boxb.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32);
            else
                boxb.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(boxa.Text) - 32) * 5 / 9);
        }

    }

    private void radioButton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "Centimeters to Inches";
        boxa.Text = "";
        boxb.Text = "";

        if (button1.IsPressed)
        {
            if (boxa.Text == "")
                boxa.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(boxb.Text) * 2.54);
            else
                boxb.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(boxa.Text)  * 0.3937008);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

Thank you :) it works now

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace UnitConverterFinal
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true) { CalcDegrees(); }
      if (radioButton2.IsChecked == true) { CalcDistance(); }

    }


    private void radioDegrees_checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    CalcDegrees();
    }

    private void radioDistance_checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    CalcDistance();
    }

    private void CalcDegrees()
    {
     //Move your calc code here
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbA.Text)) { FtoC(); return; }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbB.Text)) { CtoF(); return; }
    }

    private void CalcDistance()
    {
    //Move your calc code here
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbA.Text)) { InchToCent(); return; }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbB.Text)) { CentToInch(); return; }

    }

    private void FtoC()
    {
         tbB.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(tbA.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32); 
    }

    private void CtoF()
    {
        tbA.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(tbB.Text) - 32) * 5 / 9); 
    }

    private void InchToCent()
    {
        tbB.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(tbA.Text) * 2.54);             
    }

    private void CentToInch()
    {
        tbA.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(tbB.Text) * 0.3937008); 
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: what do you mean you're getting the same formula. When? When the radio is checked or when the button is pressed? What kind of project is this?

Comment: I'm trying to make a unit converter. this works but I keep getting the F to C formula even when I press the radio buttons (which should change the formula and text)

Comment: remove the if(button1.IsPresses) from the radio_checked methods

Comment: if I do that then I get the error "FormatException was unhandled"

Comment: thats because you have invalid strings in the Convert.ToDouble code. Make sure they are not empty values. You're setting textbox a & b to empty strings so it will always fail

Comment: I took out the boxa.Text = ""; boxb.Text = ""; and it works but I'm back to the same problem. Centimeters to inches for some reason is still using the formula for F to C

Comment: I'm thinking 1) I dont understand your UI logic or 2) you need to change the ui logic. see my answer below and try to rearrange your code to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is more like this (psuedo code btw). This is based on what I think you're UI logic is

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioDegrees.Checked) { CalcDegrees(); }
            if (radioDistance.Checked) { CalcDistance(); }
        }

        private void radioDegrees_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalcDegrees();
        }

        private void radioDistance_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalcDistance();
        }

        private void CalcDegrees()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbA.Text)) { FtoC(); return; }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbB.Text)) { CtoF(); return; }
        }

        private void CalcDistance()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbA.Text)) { InchToCent(); return; }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbB.Text)) { CentToInch(); return; }
        }

        private void FtoC()
        {
             tbB.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(tbA.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32); 
        }

        private void CtoF()
        {
            tbA.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(tbB.Text) - 32) * 5 / 9); 
        }

        private void InchToCent()
        {
            tbB.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(tbA.Text) * 2.54);             

        }

        private void CentToInch()
        {
            tbA.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(tbB.Text) * 0.3937008); 
        }
    }
```

Updated the code. I worked this in a WinForms project and it works. Try it this way.

Comment: It looks like your pseudo code reflects what I portray his code is trying to do. If value in tbA then convert that to X otherwise if value in tbB Convert to Y.

Comment: I guess I'm a tard I tried manulipating it and got a ton of errors, I'm sure if I knew more it would work but never tried it that way. I'll just stick with different buttons and texboxes (I was just trying to clean it up). Thanks again :)

Comment: Actually all I need to figure out is radiobutton1."CHECKED" it says checked is "The event Togglebutton.checked can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=".

Comment: @Hedgehodge Try the updated code. I implemented it in a win forms app and it works.

Comment: With a few corrections for visual studio 2010express it works :D Thanks a ton. Now to tweak it. V/r